# Depth of dipole trap

Tags: temperature, potential, bose-einstein-condensate, ion-traps

I am wondering about the relation between a harmonic potential (e.g. generated by a dipole trap) and temperature. I have seen couple of times that you can express the depth of the trap as a temperature. Could someone please explain the relation there?

Comment: Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trap depth is generally a energy, as stated here: https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/9902072

It is the energy difference from a free particle (no trap) to the trap bottom (lowest energy level).
The energy can be divided by the Boltzmann factor ($k_B$) to be converted to temperature.

Why do people do this?

- Converting the energy to units of µK (mikro Kelvin) makes the numbers smaller and easier to handle. Writing everything in eV (electron volt) or J (Joule) is also fine, but the numbers become small.
- Having the trap depth in units of temperature gives you a "feeling" of how hot your atoms can be in order to remain trapped. When your trap depth is 100 µK you don't attempt to capture atoms that are 1 mK hot, but you could capture atoms that are 1 µK hot. But this is only for estimation.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!

Comment: @ikarus: Mark the question as answered if you are satisfied with the reply